# Не получается подключить шрифт

Tags: шрифты

Шрифт отличается от того, что есть в макете. Не могу его подключить в код

```
 HTML:



  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Wordpress интенсив</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="promo">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="icons/owl.png" alt="logo" class="logo_img">
                    <div class="logo_text">WordPress интенсив</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </section>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.promo {
    height: 800px;
    background: url('../img/background/bg.png') center center/cover no-repeat;ЫЫ
}

.logo .logo_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo .logo_text {
    /* Style for "WordPress" */
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /* Text style for "WordPress" */
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-top: 14px;
}
```

[image: шрифт в макете]

[image: шрифт в сделанном сайте]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```